# Cisco MDS zoning a physical server

Tags: storage-area-network, cisco-ucs, zoning

I'm new to zoning using Cisco MDS (9250i) to a Cisco UCS and was shadowing one of my colleague. I noticed he used the WWPN of the Linux server output systool command. I logged in to the CIMC and compared the WWPN but they are different.

The zone to the target LUN worked, but I was just wondering if its the best practice?

If I used the WWPN of the physical server's fabric ports (from CIMC) rather than the one from Linux, will it work as well?

Comment: How different are they? are they using a VIC adapter (as they can do some unusual things?

Comment: they're very different

linux WWPN is XXXXXXXX212a0 
CIMC HBA fc0 WWPN is XXXXXXXX:9D:6C

Comment: Oh wow, so very different, really not sure why they're so different - we're more of an ESXi house and they're the same - what make/model of FC HBA are you using? Actually I just had a thought - are you using FC or FCoE, where are you looking in CIMC for your WWNs?